# Simple Html Dom returning encrypted page

Tags: php, curl, web-scraping, simple-html-dom

I am trying to scrape a webpage using simple_html_dom and cUrl also. Butin results it returning encrypted type page, (Unreadable characters).

Using Simple Html Dom

```
$url = 'http://mangafox.me/manga/world_trigger/v01/c001/2.html';
$html = file_get_html($url);
echo $html->plaintext;
```

Result is [This Encrypted Unreadable HTML](https://i.stack.imgur.com/k6D6F.png)

With Curl

```
   $ch = curl_init("http://mangafox.me/manga/world_trigger/v01/c001/2.html");
    curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, true);
    curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_BINARYTRANSFER, true);
    $content = curl_exec($ch);
    curl_close($ch);

    echo $content;
```

Result is same as above :( This Behaviour is really strange, Please help.

Comment: Try setting some headers, user-agent for example.

Answer (score 0):

Actually, the encrypted content was a GZIPed content.

Resolved it by decoding it with builtin PHP function

```
if ( ! function_exists('gzdecode'))
{

    function gzdecode($data) 
    {
        // strip header and footer and inflate

         return gzinflate(substr($data, 10, -8));
     }
 }
```

Reference :[Here is original post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20855385/php-simple-html-dom-parser-returns-gibberish)